Value of Terminal State vs. Reward in Value Iteration GridWorld
I've seen a lot of posts saying that the value of the terminal state is always 0, but a lot of examples of value iteration assign the reward (at the terminal) to be the value. For example, in the following gridworld, we have +1 and -1 as the values of the terminal states.

Does this depend on how we define the reward? Would the above example be the case where rewards depend only on the state being departed? Or does it also apply to cases where rewards depend on the state being entered?
I'm leaning towards the idea that the value for the terminal states should not be their associated reward (as in the above example) IF we define the reward to depend on the entering state s'. But if this is the case, how will the algorithm know to assign the action that leads into the terminal state for the neighboring states?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
